# Android Studio Gradle is not building third party libraries

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-library

I am using Android Studio 1.3.1 in Windows and same in Ubuntu.
In Ubuntu, everything is perfect.
But in Windows, when I compile third party libraries, the build fails and says:

> Can not find resource

The build.gradle of my module is :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.android.parking"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
}
```

the error is coming in the last line. And it is coming for every third party library,not only for this one.
When I open same project in Ubuntu, the build is successful.

The build.gradle of my project is:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
     repositories {
       jcenter()
   }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
   }
}
```

The exact error is:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':parking'.
```

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':parking:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not resolve cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3.
>        Required by:
>            parking:parking:unspecified
>   Could not resolve cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/cn/pedant/sweetalert/library/1.3/library-1.3.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/cn/pedant/sweetalert/library/1.3/library-1.3.pom'.
>   jcenter.bintray.com

I tried invalidating cache and restart, It did not work. It is compiling everything except those third party libraries.

Comment: Please post the exact **error message**. Did you try to build the project from the **command line** via `gradlew.bat clean assembleDebug`?

Comment: Please post the error/s

Comment: @JJD- Posed the error

Comment: You need the repository "mavenCentral()". Read this https://github.com/pedant/sweet-alert-dialog#setup

Comment: @Victor_J_Martin So shall I change the repository from Jcenter() to mavenCentral in project's build.gradle? And why is it working in ubuntu then? :(

Comment: @Victor_J_Martin The library is available on [MavenCentral](http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22cn.pedant.sweetalert%22%20AND%20a%3A%22library%22) **and** [jCenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/cn.pedant.sweetalert%3Alibrary/view#files).

Comment: I know that the library is available in both repos, but try to change to mavenCentral and try. I don't know what is the problem that makes the build runs on Ubuntu and not in your other OS.

Comment: @Victor_J_Martin didn't work.. I tried

Comment: What versions of Java, Gradle, etc. has in the both systems? That's weird

Comment: Java 1.7, gradle 1.3

Comment: the gradle version is same, But I am using the default open JDK in ubuntu and in Windows Oracle's

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88088/discussion-between-victor-j-martin-and-prakhar).